# Define a CASE inside SQL Statement (Need simplification)

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

The SQL Statement (SQL Server) works - but its very redundant and seems inefficient. I was wondering if there was a way to define a case statement inside a SELECT and then create conditional statements.

I'm pulling information from a table, grabbing the Primary Key INT ID and checking to see if the ID exists in another table. If it does not, then assign a 0 value - but if it does grab the ID. Then I repeat the same process to check another table.

Can someone shed some light on how to simplify this statement?

```
SELECT 
    a.[ID] AS ID, 
    a.[JOB_NUMBER] AS JOB_NUMBER, 

    -- Test to see if we have any entries in job_links_data, if not then assign 0
    CASE WHEN
       (SELECT COUNT([ID]) FROM job_links_data WHERE ([JOB_ID]=a.[ID])) = 0
    THEN 0
    ELSE
       (SELECT COUNT([ID]) FROM job_links_data WHERE ([JOB_ID]=a.[ID]))  
    END AS JOB_LINKS,

    -- If above is 0, then assign an empty string '' - else grab the title
    CASE WHEN
       (SELECT COUNT([ID]) FROM job_links_data WHERE ([JOB_ID]=a.[ID])) = 0
    THEN  ''
    ELSE
       (SELECT c.[TITLE] FROM 
            job_links_info c, 
            job_links_data b, 
            tbl_jobs a 
        WHERE (b.[JOB_LINK_INFO_ID]=c.[ID] AND b.[JOB_ID]=a.[ID]))
    END AS TITLE

FROM tbl_jobs a
WHERE (
    a.[PROJECT_ID]=25  
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider declaring a variable and using it inside your query, something like this:

```
DECLARE @JOB_LINKS int
SET @JOB_LINKS = (SELECT COUNT([ID]) FROM job_links_data WHERE ([JOB_ID]=a.[ID]))

-- And after this, your query with the variable.

SELECT 
    a.[ID] AS ID, 
    a.[JOB_NUMBER] AS JOB_NUMBER, 
    @JOB_LINKS AS JOB_LINKS,

    CASE WHEN @JOB_LINKS = 0
    THEN  ''
    ELSE -- selecting the title only when job links is not 0
       (SELECT c.[TITLE] FROM 
            job_links_info c, 
            job_links_data b, 
            tbl_jobs a 
        WHERE (b.[JOB_LINK_INFO_ID]=c.[ID] AND b.[JOB_ID]=a.[ID]))
    END AS TITLE

FROM tbl_jobs a
WHERE (
    a.[PROJECT_ID]=25  
);
```

The variable **must** be set before the statement, and this is not always possible depending on how you are executing your query.

Answer (score 1):

This just seems silly:

```
CASE WHEN
   (SELECT COUNT([ID]) FROM job_links_data WHERE ([JOB_ID]=a.[ID])) = 0
THEN 0
ELSE
   (SELECT COUNT([ID]) FROM job_links_data WHERE ([JOB_ID]=a.[ID]))  
END AS JOB_LINKS,
```

If the value is 0 then assign 0?  Replace it with:

```
(SELECT COUNT([ID]) FROM job_links_data WHERE ([JOB_ID]=a.[ID]))  AS JOB_LINKS
```

I would also advise you to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Agreed. Its silly and I did make your correction. But is there a way to assign "JOB_LINKS" to a variable so that I don't have to check it again in the next CASE statement?